# Printing an inline-XML format in PHP is not working

Tags: php, xml

So i have this java command that prints an output of inline-XML and i need it to print in browser. I'm using PHP.  I've already tried:

```
echo "<pre>";
echo htmlspecialchars($output);
echo "</pre>";
```

and still it's not printing in the browser. BTW `$output` looks like this:

```
I complained to <ORGANIZATION>Microsoft</ORGANIZATION> about <PERSON>Bill Gates</PERSON>.
  They     told me to see the mayor of <LOCATION>New York</LOCATION>.
```

Comment: It outputs nothing or the output is incorrect? Do you get any errors?

Comment: It ouputs nothing, and no errors. Its just not printing in the browser.

Comment: You must be getting an error. The code you've provided would work, https://3v4l.org/sDM78. Have you enabled reporting and checked your logs?

Comment: I've figured it out, sir. I forgot to say that $output = shell_exec("insert java command here"). I added -encoding utf-8 inside the command. Then it works. I guess the problem is in the output encoding issue.

Comment: Great, I think you can delete the question in that case because it wasn't a coding issue.